# Recursively monitor a HDFS directory spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I need to stream data from HDFS direcory via using spark streaming.

```
JavaDStream<String> lines = ssc.textFileStream("hdfs://ip:8020/directory");
```

Above does a pretty good job in monitoring an HDFS directory for new files, but it is limited to same directory level, it does'nt monitor nested directories.

I comes accross following posts which mention about adding a depth parameter to this API

https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-reviews/201502.mbox/%3C20150220121124.DBB5FE03F7@git1-us-west.apache.org%3E

https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/2765

The problem is that in spark version 1.6.1 (tested) this parameter is not present, hence i cannot use it, i dont want to change original source eighther

```
JavaDStream<String> lines = ssc.textFileStream("hdfs://ip:8020/*/*/*/");
```

some post in stack overflow mention to use above syntax, that doesnt work eighter.

Am i missing something?

Comment: isnt it this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29401809/reading-files-from-apache-spark-textfilestream ?

Comment: nope, my requirement is to recursively process directory, as number and names of subdirectory will change continously

Comment: Bump. I also have this problem and the wildcard option, using * within the HDFS dir to read from, doesn't work.

Comment: Did any of you find a good work-around to this issue?  I'm about to solve it myself and would appreciate any pointers in case you tried various approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a patch was created but never approved due to difficulties with S3 and directory depth.

https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/6588